# Beginner problems on pipe, fork and if statement

Tags: c, sockets, networking, pipe

I am learning about socket programming and I am well-know to c-programming.

Based on my c-programming knowledge, once the process inside else statement is processed. The process inside if statement should not be happened and will be killed. For instances,

```
int a = 1;
if(a == 1) process1 ;
else process2;
```

Based on the statement above, a equals to 1, so process1 should be executed and process2 will not be executed. It should be correct, I hoped so.

My question is following code

```
int main(void){
   pid_t pid;
   int pp[2];

   pipe(pp);

   pid = fork();
   if(pid == 0){
      printf("Processed pid == 0\n");
   }else{
      printf("Processed pid != 0\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And I got the following output result

```
Processed pid == 0
Processed pid != 0
```

My question is WHY the result of statement if and else is showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked up `man fork()`?

The parent gets a PID of the child (non zero) and the child gets zero, therefore the parent is running "one side" of the if, and the child "the other".

< edit >
Of course a -1 return (to the parent) indicates an error.

Comment: It means, after I executed the code above, two process will be running separately as fork is called. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly: Just like the man page says!